# Node.js In Action Book callbacks example

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js

I am working with the book Node.js in action second edition. On page 30 there is a callback example where you use display json in html the code I have below is not running and I am not sure why. I am running the code below in the proper directory using the command node .\blog_recent.js but it is not doing anything in the browser when I hit localhost:8000

> NodeJS

```
 const http = require('http');
    const fs = require('fs');
    http.createServer((req,res) => {
    if (req.url == '/') {
        fs.readFile('./titles.json', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                res.end('Server Error');
            } else {
                const titles = JSON.parse(data.toString());
                fs.readFile('./template.html', (err,data) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    res.end('Server Error');
                } else {
                    const tmpl = data.toString();
                    const html = tmpl.replace('%', titles.join('</li><li>'));
                    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    }).listen(8000, 'localhost');
```

> Json

```
    [
    "Kazakhstan is a huge country.... what goes on there?",
    "This weather is making me craaazy",
    "My neighbor sort of howls at night"
    ]
```

> HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>Latest Posts</h1>
    <ul><li>%</li></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing `res.end(html);` after `res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });`

not including the `res.end` means that the server will finish working on the request but won't tell the browser the result, therefor the browser is waiting for a response indefinitely.